# Laravel generated XML file has space at start

Tags: php, xml, laravel, laravel-4, laravel-blade

I'm generating a Google products feed using Laravel 4. I'm using a Blade file to do this, but Laravel is adding a mystery space at the very start of the output, which causes Google to reject the XML file as invalid. Any ideas why?

My controller is:

```
public function googleFeed()
{
    //generates a Google Merchant XML feed of products
    $products = DB::table('products')->get();
    $content = View::make('shop.googlefeed', ['products' => $products]);
    return Response::make($content, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

}
```

And my blade file:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
    <channel>
    <title>Title</title>
    <link>http://example</link>
    <description>Desc</description>
        @foreach ($products as $product)
                <item>
                    <g:id>{{($product->id)}}</g:id>
                    <title>{{($product->productname)}}</title>
                    <link>http://example.com/product/{{($product->slug)}}</link>
                    <description>{{($product->shortdesc)}}</description>
                    <g:image_link>{{($product->imgurlthumb)}}</g:image_link>
                    <g:price>{{($product->productprice)}} GBP</g:price>
                    <g:gtin>{{($product->gtin)}}</g:gtin>
                    <g:condition>new</g:condition>
                    <g:availability>in stock</g:availability>
                </item>
        @endforeach
    </channel>
</rss>
```

No space in the Blade file. But, the output is:

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?>
<rss xmlns:g="http://base.google.com/ns/1.0" version="2.0">
<channel>
<title>Title</title>
....
```

Why is this space added? I just can't see where it would come from! It doesn't seem like much of a problem, but it causes the feed to fail validation and is rejected by Google. Failing being able to establish the source of it, is there a way to strip it out after processing?

Many thanks.

Comment: @limonte Oops, sorry. Laravel 4.

Comment: just repeated your code in L5, and there's no this issue with whitespace.

Comment: You have whitespace somewhere else in your code, probably in an included file. Make sure you don't have a closing `?>` tag in any PHP-only files --- that's a very likely cause of your problem.

Comment: I thought about that @EdCottrell, but where would the included files be? As you can see nothing is included in that Blade file. Could it come from somewhere else? Thanks

Comment: I mean something "upstream" from your controller. Not a file included in one of the files you posted, but a file including the files you posted.

Comment: OK. So it would be limited to this controller? Or do you mean it could be in unrelated controllers or views? Is there any way I can try to isolate the source of it? Thanks - I've been tackling this for hours!

Comment: When I push your code in laravel 4, I don't get the issue, so, you probaply have a fault inside your controller/**model** or view.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I solved this when I noticed that there was a space at the start of my routes.php file. Removing this fixed the issue. Simple but frustrating, hope it helps someone else! (The space could be at the start of most any file.)

```
 <?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return "Hello";
});
...
```

To:

```
<?php
Route::get('/', function () {
    return "Hello";
});
...
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved this problem, using this funcion before download the file

```
public function googleFeed()
{
    ob_clean();
    //generates a Google Merchant XML feed of products
    $products = DB::table('products')->get();
    $content = View::make('shop.googlefeed', ['products' => $products]);
    return Response::make($content, '200')->header('Content-Type', 'text/xml');

}
```

Comment: This should not be at all necessary in Laravel.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).